# DBUnit ignores column aliases, when creating dataset from query?

Tags: mysql, dbunit

I have two datasets, which I want to compare with DBUnit: one defines as XML file, the other I am trying to create using a query:

```
dbConnection.createQueryTable("my_table", "SELECT ...");
```

Select goes over couple of tables, where the few of them has the same column names, so I am using aliases to distinguish between them. The query runs fine, but seems that while creating a dataset, DBUnit ignores the column aliases and uses the original names instead. This clearly is seen in DEBUG log:

```
01.03.13 14:18:43,228 [ DEBUG] AbstractDatabaseConnection - createQueryTable(resultName=my_table, sql=
        SELECT `table1`.`name`
            , `table2`.`label` AS `table2_label`
            , `table3`.`label`
        FROM `table1`
            , `table2`
            , `table3`
        WHERE `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`table1_id`
            AND `table2`.`id` = `table3`.`table2_id`
    ) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,228 [ DEBUG] DatabaseDataSourceConnection - getConnection() - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,228 [ DEBUG] DatabaseConfig$Configurator - Statement fetch size set to 100
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] DatabaseDataSourceConnection - getConnection() - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] DatabaseTableMetaData - The 'schemaName' from the ResultSetMetaData is empty-string and not applicable hence. Will not try to lookup column properties via DatabaseMetaData.getColumns.
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] DatabaseTableMetaData - The 'schemaName' from the ResultSetMetaData is empty-string and not applicable hence. Will not try to lookup column properties via DatabaseMetaData.getColumns.
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] DatabaseTableMetaData - The 'schemaName' from the ResultSetMetaData is empty-string and not applicable hence. Will not try to lookup column properties via DatabaseMetaData.getColumns.
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=0, columnName=name) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=0, columnName=label) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=0, columnName=label) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,240 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=1, columnName=name) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,241 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=1, columnName=label) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,241 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=1, columnName=label) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,241 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=2, columnName=name) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,241 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=2, columnName=label) - start
01.03.13 14:18:43,241 [ DEBUG] ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=2, columnName=label) - start
```

As you see - `getValue(row=X)` uses `label` as name for `table2` and `table3` columns and not `table2_label` and `label` as defined in query...

How to solve this? I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like its caused by a [change in the MYSQL Java connector](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21596)

Caused by `DatabaseTableMetaData` calling `ResultSetMetaData#getColumnName()` rather than `#getColumnLabel()`

You don't state what version of DBUnit/MySql you are using, but DBUnit 2.2 & 2.4.9 are affected with MySql connector 5.1.26.

As a workaround, the MySQL devs have included a backward compatability option, discussed in the change above.

To configure it, add a property to your JDBC url:

`jdbc:mysql://host/db_name?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true`

As per [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: Btw, I was using DBUnit 2.4.9 and MySQL Connector 5.1.26